# How can I validate an input's value on user keyboard entry?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, real-time, onchange

How to validate form's input value on user typing or on change? I am trying to read `state` but it is kind of late/ not realtime.

I am thinking of using a class variable/ property and mutate it, but I am afraid that it will offend the React's principal.

Is there a proper way to create realtime form validation like [this](https://ireade.github.io/form-validation-realtime/) in React?

Answer (score 1):

Validation is so widely used that we can find dozens of good ways to do that with react. I like to use the following:

Instead of just hold the value of your inputs on state, you could make a more complex object for each one. Let's begin defining a form with 2 inputs: `name` and `age`. The first step would be describe the form in state. Something like that:

```
state = {
    form:{
        name:{
            value : '',
            valid : true,
            rules:{
                minLength : 3
            }
        },
        age:{
            value : '',
            valid : true,
            rules:{
                isNumber : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There we have it! We now have 2 inputs that are valid on the initial render and have their own validation rules(isNumber, minLength). Now we need to write a function that validates the state on the fly. Let's write it then:

```
onChangeHandler = (key, value) =>{
    this.setState(state =>({
        ...state,
        form:{
            ...state.form,
            [key]:{
                ...state.form[key],
                value,
                valid : validate(value, state.form[key].rules)
            }
        }
    }))
}
```

Now we have a form described in state and a handler that updates the state `onChange` and validate the value of the input on each call. Now the only thing to do is write your `validate()` function and you are ready to go.

```
validate = (value, rules) => {
let valid = true

for (let key in rules) {
    switch (key) {

        case 'minLength':
            valid = valid && minLengthValidator(value, rules[key])
            break

        case 'isNumber':
            valid = valid && isNumberValidator(value)
            break

        default: break
    }
}

    return valid
}
```

Now the validators...

```
minLengthValidator = (value, rule) => (value.length >= rule)
isNumberValidator = value => !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)
```

Done! Now call your inputs like that:

```
render(){
    const { form } = this.state
    return(
        <TextField value={form.name.value} onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler('name',e.target.value)} />
    )
}
```

Every time that the input changes the validate function will be triggered, now you have real time form validation, is up to you apply the respectives styles according to the `valid` prop.

Answer (score 0):

we have to define a validateProperty(input) and use it in our onChange method. here is a basic example how to implement it.first define your state. assuming that i have a form with username and password inputs.

state = { account: { username: "", password: "" }, errors: {} };

```
validateProperty = (input) => {
    if (input.name === "username") {
      if (input.value.trim() === "") return "username is required";
    }
    if ((input.name = "password")) {
      if (input.value.trim() === "") return "password is required";
    }
  };
```

now we have to use it in on handleChange

e.currentTarget returns input field and i named it as input and did object destructuring

```
handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors }; 
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];
    const account = { ...this.state.account };
    account[input.name] = input.value; //currentTarget returns input field
    this.setState(() => ({ account, errors }));
  };
```

for each input field I added "name" attribute. so errors[input.name] will be errors[e.currentTarget.name] if name="username" username field, if name="password" password field.